# Jest check if an elements attribute exists

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, chai, enzyme

I want to check with jest if the following svg path element contains the attribute `d`
`<path id="TrendLine" fill="none" stroke="black"  d="M170,28.76363636363638C170,28.76363636363638,221.46221083573664,189.150059910"></path>` 
How do I use jest to search for specific attribute in an element?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [enzyme's shallow method](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html) to render your component and then to check the props on the path element:

```
// at the top of your test file file:
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

...

it('should render path element with the expected d attribute', () => {
  // shallowly render your component:
  const wrapper = shallow(<Component />);

  // find the path element using a css selector
  const trendline = wrapper.find('path#TrendLine');

  // make assertion
  expect(trendline.props()).toHaveProperty('d', 'M170,28.76363636363638C170,28.76363636363638,221.46221083573664,189.150059910');
});
```

Comment: The `d` values might change, how do I check if `d` exists, without considering the values in `d`

Comment: You can do that by just calling toHaveProperty with the first argument: .toHaveProperty(‘d’)

Comment: Tried it before and got this error, `Error: Invalid Chai property: toHaveProperty`, is there any other way of checking if d exists?

Comment: that's odd which version of jest are you using?

Comment: but yep the props() function returns an object of that element's properties so you could check if it exists like this: `expect(trendline.props().hasOwnProperty('d')).toBe(true);`

Comment: `expect(trendline.props().hasOwnProperty('d')).toBe(true);` did the trick, thanks!